# How do I handle an error when using rust-websocket so that only that connection fails and not the entire program?

Tags: asynchronous, error-handling, websocket, rust

I am trying to get a Rust WebSocket server up and running. I started with the [example code for an async websocker server](https://github.com/cyderize/rust-websocket/blob/7bd2defaf98c3dec8a9b5e7dc93cbbc887e97d5a/examples/async-server.rs).

Every time I get an `Io` error, like when the connection is interrupted, the entire program ends without any error. I modified the code on line 26 of the example to:

```
.map_err(|InvalidConnection {error, ..}| {
    println!("Error:{:?}",error);
    return error;
})
```

This prints the error, but does not prevent the program from stopping only the single connection and not crashing itself.

The most common error I get is:

```
Io(Error { repr: Custom(Custom { kind: Other, error: Stream(Error { repr: Custom(Custom { kind: ConnectionAborted, error: StringError("unexpected EOF observed") }) }) }) })
```

Comment: But what is your question ?

Comment: How to handle the Io Error so my program does not die and drops all other connections...

Comment: @Hahihula Please edit your question to clearly ask it. A question without highlighted and clear interrogation is not good in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with some help from rust IRC channel i found the solution. I've just replaced the error with None and filtered it out.

```
.map(Some).or_else(|_| -> Result<_, ()> { Ok(None) }).filter_map(|x| x)
```

Maybe this info will help someone with similar problem.