# Running websocket and http server on the same port (Rust, hyper)

Tags: websocket, rust, hyper

I want to write a webserver using Rust, Hyper and websocket-rs. The webserver must be able to handle http requests AND websocket requests **on the same port**. I used the official sample (`async-server.rs`: https://github.com/cyderize/rust-websocket/blob/master/examples/async-server.rs) and tried to modify it. My idea was to change the error handling. If the client's request is a simple http request then do not return an error, but spawn a future which handles the request instead.

Based on another SO question ([How do I handle an error when using rust-websocket so that only that connection fails and not the entire program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974034/how-do-i-handle-an-error-when-using-rust-websocket-so-that-only-that-connection/45055116#45055116)) I changed the error handling from the sample.

This is the old code:

```
.map_err(|InvalidConnection {error, ..}| {
    println!("Error:{:?}",error);
    return error;
})
```

Here is my new code:

```
.map(Some).or_else(|_| -> Result<_, ()> {
    // SPAWN THE FUTURE
    Ok(None)
})
```

This is where I am stuck. The sample code calls a function `spawn_future`, which expects a parameter (`upgrade.reject()`) which is not available in my code since I do not have access to an `upgrade` structure. I tried a few other things (i.e. calling `handle.spawn_fn`) but the compiler never liked what I did. (I could paste some of the compiler errors, but I do not think that they would improve the quality of my post.)

**Here is my question**: What is the recommended way to write an asynchronous server which can handle http requests AND websocket requests on the same port? If my approach is correct: can you please help me to fill the `SPAWN THE FUTURE` line?

Additional context (if you haven't noticed yet): I am a total Rust beginner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be some docs on this in the rust-websocket documentation [here](http://cyderize.github.io/rust-websocket/doc/websocket/server/upgrade/sync/struct.HyperRequest.html)

Pasting from the docs:

```
use hyper::server::{Server, Request, Response};
use websocket::Message;
use websocket::sync::server::upgrade::IntoWs;
use websocket::sync::server::upgrade::HyperRequest;

Server::http("0.0.0.0:80").unwrap().handle(move |req: Request, res: Response| {
    match HyperRequest(req).into_ws() {
        Ok(upgrade) => {
            // `accept` sends a successful handshake, no need to worry about res
            let mut client = match upgrade.accept() {
                Ok(c) => c,
                Err(_) => panic!(),
            };

            client.send_message(&Message::text("its free real estate"));
        },

        Err((request, err)) => {
            // continue using the request as normal, "echo uri"
            res.send(b"Try connecting over ws instead.").unwrap();
        },
    };
})
.unwrap();
```

Comment: Thank you. This was well hidden in the documentation. I would not have found it.

Comment: The link is broken, cythedize appears to have disappeared.