# Is there any way to run Tungstenite on the same port as hyper?

Tags: https, rust

I'm trying to make a web server in Rust for a simple browser game. I want the server to be able to deliver pages through HTTPS, but also be able to communicate through WebSockets. I'm planning to put this server on Heroku, but since they only allow one port per application I have to make the WebSocket server operate on the same port as the other HTTPS code.

It seems like [this is possible with crates like `rust-websocket`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45806359/1753929), but that crate uses an outdated version of `hyper` and seems to be no longer maintained. The crate `tokio_tungstenite` is much more up to date.

The problem is that both `hyper` and `tungstenite` have their own implementation of the HTTP protocol that WebSockets operate over with no way to convert between the two. This means that once an HTTPS request has been parsed by either `hyper` or `tungstenite` there is no way to continue the processing by the other part, so you can't really try to connect the WebSocket and match on an error in `tungstenite` and process it by `hyper`, nor can you parse the request by `hyper` and check if it's a WebSocket request and send it over to `tungstenite`. Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but it's quite fiddly. You'll have to use `tokio-tungstenite`, do the handshake yourself (check header, set response headers) and spawn a new future on the runtime that will handle the websockets connection. The new future can be created by calling `on_upgrade()` on the request body with the latest version of hyper, and the connection can then be passed to `tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream::from_raw_socket` to turn it into a websockets connection.

Example handler (note that this doesn't fully check the request headers and assumes we want an upgrade):

```
fn websocket(req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, &'static str> {
    // TODO check other header
    let key = match req.headers().typed_get::<headers::SecWebsocketKey>() {
        Some(key) => key,
        None => return Err("failed to read ws key from headers"),
    };
    let websocket_future = req
        .into_body()
        .on_upgrade()
        .map_err(|err| eprintln!("Error on upgrade: {}", err))
        .and_then(|upgraded| {
            let ws_stream = tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream::from_raw_socket(
                upgraded,
                tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::protocol::Role::Server,
                None,
            );
            let (sink, stream) = ws_stream.split();
            sink.send_all(stream)
                .map(|_| ())
                .map_err(|err| error!("{}", err))
        });
    hyper::rt::spawn(websocket_future);
    let mut upgrade_rsp = Response::builder()
        .status(StatusCode::SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS)
        .body(Body::empty())
        .unwrap();
    upgrade_rsp
        .headers_mut()
        .typed_insert(headers::Upgrade::websocket());
    upgrade_rsp
        .headers_mut()
        .typed_insert(headers::Connection::upgrade());
    upgrade_rsp
        .headers_mut()
        .typed_insert(headers::SecWebsocketAccept::from(key));
    Ok(upgrade_rsp)
}
```

Comment: where are you getting the  `typed_check` and `headers::SecWebsocketKey` can you please include imports

Comment: @nikoss This was a while back, but I think both are part of the `headers` crate https://docs.rs/headers/0.3.4/headers/

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible to do that, the `tungstenite` and `tokio-tungstenite` allow you to specify custom headers (there are helpers functions for that, prefixed with `hdr`), so depending on the `hyper` version you use, if you can convert a request to some form, when the headers can be extracted, you can pass them to `tungstenite`.

You might also want to try `warp` crate, it's built on top of `hyper` and it uses `tungstenite` under the hood for the websocket support, so if you want to write your own version of `warp`, you can take a look at the source code (the source code may contain hints on how to use `hyper` and `tungstenite` together).

Comment: warp is nice and all but a router with as little as 15 endpoints take around 3 minutes to compile. Same code ported to routerify takes 3 seconds